# Static IP for up VPN?

Tags: windows, linux, vpn, static-ip

To setup a VPN is it necessary to have a static IP?

Also VPN is a new concept to me any help (guides) and tips for setting up a VPN Server and Client in Windows (Xp and 7)

*(alternatively Linux guides are also welcome as I do have a Linux setup on one of my desktops)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't need a static IP.  You just have to know the current IP to connect to.  I use OpenVPN on my WRT54G on my residential cable connection.  My router acts as a server, and it auto-registers with DynDNS.org whenever the IP changes.  At worst my VPN would fail for a matter of minutes as my dynamic DNS times out.

As for help setting it up, what are you trying to do?  What systems are you trying to connect and why?  Knowing that would help to get the best VPN setup for what you're doing.

Comment: secure file sharing with friends located else where and probably to access files from my home computer when im elsewhere

Comment: I don't know much about the Windows PPTP VPN setup, but its probably enough to do what you're looking for.  I would install OpenVPN on your Linux system, but that's probably overkill for what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you are trying to achieve with your VPN. Strictly talking, no, it's not necessary.

If you are trying to establish a VPN between two offices, probably is better to do it using static IPs. It will be a lot easier and probably more secure.

It's a little bit old, but still valuable, since you told that any help is welcome. [VPN HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/VPN-HOWTO/)

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not necessary to have a static IP address; you can access the server via a domain name if you use a [dynamic dns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS) service (most modern DSL routers can register themselves with such a service automatically).

Answer (score 0):

On the Server side IP should be static and on the client side dynamic IPs will do and they are doing in most current implementations.Your scenario will be more reliable and efficient if you use static IP addresses(of course public IPs) at all your sites but this will affect your corporate budget.

Baumgart's suggested solution will work but the configuration steps may cause headache for a novice like me and the reliability and availability of corporate network is a question mark for me at this stage.

This reply is "To the best of my knowledge".